# mvc add query string variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently in my rewriterules.config, I have the following rule set up:

```
  <rule name="PublicUrl" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^public-url.html$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="public-url.html?query=string" />
 </rule>
```

I’m using MVC version 4 and would like to know if there is a way to add the query string (needed for backwards compat.) in RouteConfig.cs instead of doing so in rewriterules.config.

The action result in the controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Test(string strParam)
{

    return View("BuildingListingPage");
}
```

The routing in RouteConfig.cs looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Publicurl",
       url: " public-url.html ",

            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Test", strParam = "hi there”,  querystring = "addme" }
       );
```

My attempt here was to have the querystring in the defaults get appended to querystring variables. If I would be using an actionlink or URLHelper from a view, I believe that parameters that do not match up, are indeed appended to the query string.

I also tried creating a custom class that implements RouteBase and adding the values to the RouteValue, but that did not accomplish my goal.

The question here is if there is a way to append a variable to the query string variables from within Routeconfig.cs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the purpose of your configuration is.  If you just want to generate a link within your application with a query string, then you can add a query string when generating a link.

Assume the following route configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Publicurl",
                url: "public-url.html",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Test" }
);
```

You can generate a link for this route with a query string like so:

```
@Html.RouteLink("My Link", "Publicurl", new { strParam = "hi there", querystring  = "addme" })
```

If you're just concerned about the values being picked up from the controller that you are using to process this request, you can just add them into your Controller's Action method and they will be bound automatically.  Ensure that they are identically named as you would enter them on the query string:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    // strParam and querystring will bound automatically, rename as appropriate
    public ActionResult Index(string strParam, string querystring)
    {
        // Do something with the values

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand these options can work in some cases, but in this case, public-url.html is a url that is currently live and public, though not a link from anywhere on the site. So, The RouteLink option doesn't work well. The issue with the other option is that I need it to actually be added as a query string in Request.QueryString for legacy reasons.

Comment: Ok, so you want a route that links to a page that is external to your MVC project but will be on the same server?

Comment: Not exactly. I will try to clarify. A user enter in www.domain/public-url.html. I want the user to get redirected to www.domain/public-url.html?querystring=value. I don't need the user to see the querystring, though I don't mind. Currently, I have this set up in the rewriterules.config file and it working 100% fine. I wanted to know if I could do a similar thing in the routeconfig.cs or sometime before the code hits the controller. I'm looking for something comparable to the way the "unmatched" parameters in your Html.RouteLink sample adds actual querystring parameters.